# What is a good way to extract a url within a url in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Given `url = 'http://www.foo.com/bar?u=http://example.com/yyy/zzz.jpg&aaa=bbb&ccc=ddd'`

What is a good way to extract `http://example.com/yyy/zzz.jpg`?

EDIT:
I would like to extract the second url.

Comment: I would like to extract the second url, regardless of the `u=` param.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do :-

```
require 'uri'

url = 'http://www.foo.com/bar?u=http://example.com/yyy/zzz.jpg&aaa=bbb&ccc=ddd'

uri = URI(url)
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).select { |_,b| b[/^http(s)?/] }.map(&:last)
# => ["http://example.com/yyy/zzz.jpg"]
# or something like
Hash[URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)]['u'] # => "http://example.com/yyy/zzz.jpg"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
require "uri"
URI.extract("text here http://foo.example.org/bla and here mailto:test@example.com and here also.")
# => ["http://foo.example.org/bla", "mailto:test@example.com"]
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Comment: Wow, this is really cool. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for nested URLs...

Comment: `extract` finds URL-like patterns, however it does nothing to decode the components of the query. In the example given by the OP it returns the entire string, because it is all URL-like, and misses the URL in the 'u' parameter. `URI.extract(url) # => ["http://www.foo.com/bar?u=http://example.com/yyy/zzz.jpg&aaa=bbb&ccc=ddd"]`

Answer (score 0):

Using Ruby 2.0+:

```
require 'uri'

url = 'http://www.foo.com/bar?u=http://example.com/yyy/zzz.jpg&aaa=bbb&ccc=ddd'
uri = URI.parse(url)
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h['u'] # => "http://example.com/yyy/zzz.jpg"
```

For Ruby < 2.0:

```
require 'uri'

url = 'http://www.foo.com/bar?u=http://example.com/yyy/zzz.jpg&aaa=bbb&ccc=ddd'
uri = URI.parse(url)
Hash[URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)]['u'] # => "http://example.com/yyy/zzz.jpg"
```

The [Addressable](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/) gem is very full-featured, and follows the specs better than URI. The same thing can be done using:

```
require 'addressable/uri'

url = 'http://www.foo.com/bar?u=http://example.com/yyy/zzz.jpg&aaa=bbb&ccc=ddd'
uri = Addressable::URI.parse(url)
uri.query_values['u'] # => "http://example.com/yyy/zzz.jpg"
```